# Can I get the dependency tree before webpack starts to build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, tree

Does webpack expose the dependency tree before the build is sealed? I have searched all through the compiler instance, but have found nothing about a dependency tree. It seems that there should be one hidden in that object somewhere, because webpack has to know what this tree is in order to later output the stats.json.

I've tried using the `dependency-tree` npm package, but it doesn't support some things I have in my webpack config, so the tree is incomplete.

Comment: The question, as currently formulated, is unlikely to result in good answers. It looks like an XY problem, but the question does not state what problem getting the dependency tree is supposed to solve. I've run into many situations with webpack where getting the tree could have been useful to solve a problem, but turned out to not be necessary. So there's a whole set of problems where the answer is "You don't need the tree, here's how you do Y without it". There's also a significant possibility that the answer is that it is impossible do get a tree *for the purpose of doing Y*.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov What you see there does not satisfy getting "the dependency tree *before webpack starts to build*", as specified in the title of the question asked here, or "expose the dependency tree *before the build is sealed*", as specified in the body of the question. What's shown in that issue is how to get a dependency tree *after webpack is completely done building*.

Answer (score 25):

**TL;DR:** Yes, you can access the dependency tree just before it's being sealed.

To do this, add the following code to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
class AccessDependenciesPlugin {
  apply (compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('AccessDependenciesPlugin', compilation => {
      compilation.hooks.finishModules.tap('AccessDependenciesPlugin', modules => {
        /*
        |---------------------------------------------------
        | Here we go, `modules` is what we're looking for!
        |---------------------------------------------------
        */
      })
    })
  }
}


module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new AccessDependenciesPlugin()
  ]
}
```

For more details, see the explanation below.

---

### The hook we're looking for

We can access the pre-sealed dependency tree with the `finishModules` compilation hook.

---

### How do we know?

Since the webpack hook docs are very minimal (to say the least), we had to read webpack source code to be sure it's what we're looking for:

The last thing the compiler does before sealing the dependency tree is "finishing" it.

- This happens in [Compiler.js, line 492](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/8e6a012dbbb1526db1da753b61c43e8c61b3379f/lib/Compiler.js#L492)

Finishing the dependency tree offers a hook on the compilation.

- [`finishModules` hook in the webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/#finishmodules)
- The hook is being called in [`Compilation.js`, line 828](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/949890acdf1d00d9e53054b56ad3e7215215416d/lib/Compilation.js#L828)

---

### Code example

We create a plugin called `AccessDependenciesPlugin`:

```
// Basic webpack plugin structure
class AccessDependenciesPlugin {
  apply (compiler) {

  }
}
```

To use a compilation hook, we need to get access to the `compilation` object first. We do that with the `compilation` hook:

```
class AccessDependenciesPlugin {
  apply (compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('AccessDependenciesPlugin', compilation => {
      // We have access to the compilation now!
    })
  }
}
```

Now we tap the `finishModules` hook of the `compilation`:

```
class AccessDependenciesPlugin {
  apply (compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('AccessDependenciesPlugin', compilation => {
      compilation.hooks.finishModules.tap('AccessDependenciesPlugin', modules => {
        // Here we go, `modules` is what we're looking for!
      })
    })
  }
}
```

The `modules` parameter of that hook is an array of webpack modules with their dependencies and basically all other data available about them.

Last but not least, we need to add the plugin to our webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new AccessDependenciesPlugin()
  ]
}
```

And we're done.

---

Hope this helps.

---

### Bonus Content: webpack 3

Per request in the comments: Here's the version of the `AccessDependenciesPlugin` for the legacy plugin system of webpack 3.

```
class AccessDependenciesPlugin {
  apply (compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('compilation', compilation => {
      compilation.plugin('finish-modules', modules => {
        /*
        |---------------------------------------------------
        | Here we go, `modules` is what we're looking for!
        |---------------------------------------------------
        */
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with webpack 3? I see this hooks are available only with webpack 4.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the hook already existed back in webpack 3 (in kebab-case though, and back then hooks were accessed differently than described above): https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/webpack-3/lib/Compilation.js#L561

Comment: @SubhenduKundu I've added a webpack 3 compatible version of the plugin to my original answer.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the line of code from [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/690) will help you out:

"Compile with `webpack --profile --json > stats.json`

(node.js API: `{ profile: true }` and `stats.toJson()`)

Go to http://webpack.github.io/analyse/#modules

Load your stats file (It's not uploaded, the analyse tools is a client only tool).

Wait a bit until the graph has been stabilized."

If that's not what you need, then I'd look into @Loilo 's answer - more complicated, but probably more what you need too.